# python logging change format inside function

Tags: python, logging

I have a python script that calls some long functions. I would like to change the logging format inside the functions.

Something like:

```
def funz1():
  logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s FUNZ1:%(levelname)s:% message)s',
  x = 3
  logging.info('x is defined')
  return


def runner()
    logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s Runner:%(levelname)s: %(message)s',
   z = 10
   logging.info("z is defined") # RUNNER format
   funz1() # The generated log must be FUNZ1 format
   v = 20
   logging.info("v is defined")  # RUNNER format
```

EDIT: 
In addition to the format I would like to change also the loglevel

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: This does not work.  I always get the `RUNNER` format